# Hibernate4 Proxool 0.9.1

Tags: hibernate, proxool

I use Proxool 0.9.1.

Since Hibernate 4.x, ProxoolConnectionProvider had been moved to org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal packet (in jar: ${hibernate-release-4.x}/lib/optional/proxool/hibernate-proxool-4.x.jar).

When I upgrade to 4.x from 3.x (the configuration did not change), it always tells me

```
Exception: the url can not be null
```

...so I traced the Hibernate source code and found that the method `public void configure(Properties props)` in ProxoolConnectionProvider has never been called, so all attributes in ProxoolConnectionProvider are null.

Can anyone help me resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

This occurs due to a bug in Hibernate 4.x ([HHH-7289](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-7289))

You can work around the issue by extending org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.ProxoolConnectionProvider and implementing the org.hibernate.service.spi.Configurable interface. For example:

```
public class ConfigurableProxoolConnectionProvider extends ProxoolConnectionProvider implements Configurable
    @Override
    public void configure( final Map configurationValues ) {
        final Map<?,?> configuration = (Map<?,?>) configurationValues;
        final Properties properties = new Properties( );
        for ( final Map.Entry entry : configuration.entrySet() ) {
            properties.setProperty(
                String.valueOf( entry.getKey() ),
                String.valueOf( entry.getValue() ) );
        }       
        super.configure( properties );
    }
}
```

Then reference the extending class (e.g. xxx.yyy.ConfigurableProxoolConnectionProvider) in your hibernate properties under 'hibernate.connection.provider_class'.